# Where is the best place to invoke removeOnTabSelectedListener

Tags: android

I am using TabLayout and according to the documentation, [setOnTabSelectedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#setOnTabSelectedListener) is deprecated and we should use addOnTabSelectedListener(OnTabSelectedListener) and removeOnTabSelectedListener(OnTabSelectedListener) instead.

The question is : where do I have to invoke removeOnTabSelectedListener(OnTabSelectedListener), I would say onDestroy() callBack am I right?

Comment: Can you describe more of what your use case is or provide some sample code? I am not sure if you need to call this at all unless you are dynamically removing and adding tabs and their associated listeners

Comment: My activity implements TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener and I have overridden all required functions. In the callBack onCreate I initialize the TabLayout by adding tabs and the listener (which actually is the keyword this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats right, you can remove the listener in `onDestroy()` method or in `onPause()` method. But if you do that, dont forget to add the listener in `onCreate()` or in `onResume()`.
Also, I must say is a unusual situation, regularly we dont have to remove the listener because when the activity is destroyed, it will be destroyed as well.